blazor client side .net core how to get username in server api from oidc?
hello i have some blazor project
in client side :
 builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(opt =>
 {
     opt.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://x.y.z/oidc";
     opt.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "client";
     opt.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
     opt.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Remove("profile"); 
     opt.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";   
 });

  var IHttpServiceClient = builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IBaseHttpService,BaseHttpService>();

  builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

  IHttpServiceClient.AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

and handler is simple:

public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler:AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider , NavigationManager nav) :base(provider, nav)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(authorizedUrls: new[] { nav.BaseUri });
    }
}

and this way it works  authorize as should / redirrect back after login etc , on client side i can
username = (await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User.Identity!.Name!;`

and i have username / client side is ok.
and now server side / api
 builder.Services
 .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
 .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
 {      
     options.Authority = `https://x.y.z/oidc`;
     options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
     options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
 });

and now on some api endpoint i need the same USERNAME from this barer token
how to get it?
string username = User.Identity.Name;  // is empty  / screenshot bellow
 string username = User.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).First().Value; // is close / please check screenshot bellow

 why name is null?
and here in claims - NameIdentifier is close to my login but there is some GUID also before login / my login is Emi as on screenshot bellow but i do not want this guid before my name

should i remove this guid and take what is after : ? is there better way?
how i should get this login properrly ? In api / from token?
thanks and regards
--------------edit
in frontend when i do
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @foreach (var claim in @context.User.Claims)
        {
            <p>@claim.Type : @claim.Value</p>
        }
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

then i get
auth_time : 171xxx7995

jti : c9e59bxxxxxxxx77a38e4a

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier : f:2819xxxxxxxxx2583c6c9df:Emi

typ : ID

session_state : 331984xxxxxxxx2918950b

sid : 331984dxxxxxxxxxxx8950b

email_verified : false

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress : xxx.emixx@xxxxe.com

name : emi

so name is in this claims but it is not passed dirrectly to api ?

I am assuming this integrated with Azure. If so, you need to also include the username claim or any other claim that wil meet your needs. Take a look at the photo below to see how you can configure this:
Configuring username Claim
After you configured it, you can do the following. Build a method that will be able to search through all the claims and call this whenever you need it at any razor page. For example for client side claim:
private AuthenticatedUserModel GetUserClaimsFromAuthenticationAsync(AuthenticationState authState)
{
     var claims = authState.User.Claims; 
     var objectId = claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("objectidentifier")).Value; 
     var displayName = claims.First(x => x.Type.Equals("name")).Value; 
     var emailAddress = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Contains("emailaddress"))?.Value ?? null;
}


hello thanks for  answer / it is not azure / it is Keycloak / but same thing. but name is in claims and IN FRONTEND i see it - i edited and showed claims in FRONTEND . but this name is not sended to api / why ? nameidentifier  is also visible there and passed to api...?

Hello, all good. I do not have heaps of experience with keycloack, but if for example you are using Blazor for client, Web Api for back-end, and azure, you have to configure oidc token claims for both the client and back-end auth applications. This way both client and back-end have the same claims. It seems to be that in your case, only the client side have those claims added and not the backend. in this case, backend does not access the claims directly from the token request, but azure sends them through when server requests these...
